# Locate an element and change the class

Tags: jquery

I am trying to change the class of a `div` from **divPrintDetailed** to  **divPrintSelected**

```
<div id= "MainDiv" class ="MainDiv">
 <div id ="PartialViewDiv">
  <div class="ui-Submenu"> </div>
  <div id="reportContainer" class="divPrintDetailed"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

the following line of code doesn't do the job. where am i doing wrong.

```
 $('#MainDiv').find('div.divPrintDetailed').attr('class', 'divPrintSelected');
```

Comment: When are you setting that? Before or after the element? Or in document ready?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/S9atR/2/)** with both versions.

```
$('#MainDiv').find('div.divPrintDetailed').removeClass('divPrintDetailed').addClass('divPrintSelected');
```

and change your html for the MainDiv so it has a ID:

```
<div id="MainDiv" class ="MainDiv">
```

You can also use [toggleClasse()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) like:

```
$('#MainDiv').find('div.divPrintDetailed,div.divPrintSelected').toggleClass('divPrintDetailed divPrintSelected');
```

Answer (score 2):

Your MainDiv needs an ID, not two classes.

Your method works once you fix the missing ID issue, but you could also try:

```
$('#MainDiv').find('div.divPrintDetailed').removeClass('divPrintDetailed').addClass('divPrintSelected');
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/DaKkU/)**

Comment: in the jsFiddle, how can i see the change?

Comment: Open the inspector or dev tools and inspect the document.

Comment: but both times the number is red

Comment: @Aris - comment out the jQuery and you'll see it's blue at first.

Comment: +1 very nice. however with the inspect tool of chrome, the class remains the old one. am i missing something?

Comment: @Aris - you must be. When using Chrome you can see the original class is removed and the new class added.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35162/discussion-between-aris-and-j08691)